# Regex to extract static text and number using only regular expression

Tags: regex

I am completely new to this regular expression.
But I tried to write the regular expression to get some static text and phone number for the below text

> "password":"password123:cityaddress:mailaddress:9233321110:gender:45"

I written like below to extract this : `"password":9233321110`

```
(([\"]password[\"][\s]*:{1}[\s]*))(\d{10})?
```

regex link for demo:
https://regex101.com/r/2vNpMU/2

the correct regexp gives full match as `"password":9233321110` in regex tool

I am not using any programming language here, this is for network packet capture at F5 level.

Please help me with the regexp;

Comment: @Sweeper, Criteria/resultant extracted text  is "password":9233321110

Comment: `"password"\s*:\s*"[^\s"]*:\K\d{10}`, see https://regex101.com/r/TaOa4p/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks for regexp, It matches/full match result is, only phonumber. How can I conncatenate result with "password" as well

Comment: `"password": + YourRegexExtractMethod(/"password"\s*:\s*"[^\s"]*:\K\d{10}/)`. Or, https://regex101.com/r/TaOa4p/2.

Comment: Thanks again Wikitor, Is there way to substitute $1 and $2 as part of regexp; and it will give full match as expected result?

Comment: No, it is not possible with regex pattern, it cannot match disjoint pieces of text within one match operation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `/^([^:]+)(?::[^:]+){3}:([^:]+)/` for this.

Explained (more detailed [explanation at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LK1iQf/1)):

- `^` matches from the start of the string
- `(…)` is the first capture group. This will collect that initial `"password"`

  - `[^:]+` matches one or more non-colon characters
- `(?:…)` is a non-capturing group (it collects nothing for later)

  - `:[^:]+` matches a colon and then 1+ non-colons
- `{3}` instructs us to match the previous item (the non-capturing group) 3 times
- `:` matches a literal colon
- `([^:]+)` captures a match of 1+ non-colons, which will get us `9233321110` in this example

The first capture group is typically stored as `$1` or the first item of the returned array. (In Javascript, the zeroth item is the full match and item index 1 is the first capture group.) The second capture group is `$2`, etc.

To always match the `"password"` key, hard-code it: `/^("password")(?::[^:]+){3}:([^:]+)/`

Here's a live snippet demonstrating it:

```js
x = `"password":"password123:cityaddress:mailaddress:9233321110:gender:45"`;
match = x.match(/^([^:]+)(?::[^:]+){3}:([^:]+)/);
if (match) console.log(match[1] + ":" + match[2]);
else console.log("no match");
```